# How to win a Civ V game with super powerful adversary

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing a Civ V game in a standard map with 2 continents. I thought I was doing fairly well this time, but when I met the civs in the other continent, I discovered a super powerful civ.
Time has passed and the situation is more or less the same. I dominate my continent, but Siam is so much more powerful than me that I'm losing hope of winning the game. The rank is something like this:

1. Siam: 1500
2. Rome (me): 650
3. Others between 300 and 500

The year is about 1800AD. I am gradually improving my situation with my neighbours, so I'm not too afraid of them.

Which strategy should I follow?

Comment: I think it would help if you explain in what ways is Siam more powerful, other than territory. Do they have more advanced technology? Bigger army? More social policies? More allies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Score is mostly an indication of territory, but it doesn't necessarily translate to winning the game.  Think about all the different victory conditions possible, and pick one that minimizes Siam's advantage.

- Cultural: This is probably tough to switch to late in the game, but if you're far enough along in the social policy tree, you might be able to push for it.
- Diplomatic: Throw everything towards getting the United Nations, and then save enough money to buy off the city states.
- Science: I'd advise against this one, Siam's territory advantage translates to a big science advantage, you need to win before they finish their spaceship.
- Domination: Remember that you don't need to defeat their entire empire, just take all the capitals.  If you can take out your neighbor's capitals, you have a shot at a surgical strike on Siam's capital to win.  Don't underestimate the computer's defenses though, they don't go down easily.

Diplomatic might be your best shot, although Siam has likely bought off enough city states to make it difficult.  Cultural will only work if you're already well-positioned for it.  Otherwise, go for Domination and focus on the capitals.

Comment: Thanks bwarner. Since I'm doing fairly well economically I suppose I'll try a diplo victory.